# Using smart pointers for class members

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I'm having trouble understanding the usage of smart pointers as class members in C++11. I have read a lot about smart pointers and I think I do understand how `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`/`weak_ptr` work in general. What I don't understand is the real usage. It seems like everybody recommends using `unique_ptr` as the way to go almost all the time. But how would I implement something like this:

```
class Device {
};

class Settings {
    Device *device;
public:
    Settings(Device *device) {
        this->device = device;
    }

    Device *getDevice() {
        return device;
    }
};    

int main() {
    Device *device = new Device();
    Settings settings(device);
    // ...
    Device *myDevice = settings.getDevice();
    // do something with myDevice...
}
```

Let's say I would like to replace the pointers with smart pointers. A `unique_ptr` would not work because of `getDevice()`, right? So that's the time when I use `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr`? No way of  using `unique_ptr`? Seems to me like for most cases `shared_ptr` makes more sense unless I'm using a pointer in a really small scope?

```
class Device {
};

class Settings {
    std::shared_ptr<Device> device;
public:
    Settings(std::shared_ptr<Device> device) {
        this->device = device;
    }

    std::weak_ptr<Device> getDevice() {
        return device;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Device> device(new Device());
    Settings settings(device);
    // ...
    std::weak_ptr<Device> myDevice = settings.getDevice();
    // do something with myDevice...
}
```

Is that the way to go? Thanks very much!

Comment: It helps to be really clear as to lifetime, ownership and possible nulls. For example, having passed `device` to the constructor of `settings`, do you want to still be able to refer to it in the calling scope, or only via `settings`? If the latter, `unique_ptr` is useful. Also, do you have a scenario where the return value of `getDevice()` is `null`. If not, just return a reference.

Comment: Yes, a `shared_ptr` is correct in 8/10 cases. The other 2/10 are split between `unique_ptr` and `weak_ptr`. Also, `weak_ptr` is generally used to break circular references; I'm not sure that your usage would be considered correct.

Comment: First of all, what ownership do you want for the `device` data member? You first have to decide that.

Comment: Ok, I understand that as the caller I could use a `unique_ptr` instead and give the ownership up when calling the constructor, if I know I won't need it anymore for now. But as the designer of the `Settings` class I don't know if the caller wants to keep a reference as well. Maybe the device will be used in many places. Ok, maybe that's exactly your point. In that case, I would not be the sole owner and that's when I would use shared_ptr, I guess. And: so smart points do replace pointers, but not references, right?

Comment: this->device = device; Also use initialization lists.

Comment: As I posted on the accepted answer, there are many implied limitations you accept by making a `unique_ptr` a member variable, probably chief among them is the implicit deletion of the standard copy constructor. This deletion possibly makes the use of your class highly unintuitive for any programmer downstream.

See:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030081/copy-constructor-for-a-class-with-unique-ptr

Answer (score 231, accepted):

> A `unique_ptr` would not work because of `getDevice()`, right?

No, not necessarily. What is important here is to determine the appropriate **ownership policy** for your `Device` object, i.e. who is going to be the owner of the object pointed to by your (smart) pointer.

Is it going to be the instance of the `Settings` object *alone*? Will the `Device` object have to be destroyed automatically when the `Settings` object gets destroyed, or should it outlive that object?

In the first case, `std::unique_ptr` is what you need, since it makes `Settings` the only (unique) owner of the pointed object, and the only object which is responsible for its destruction.

Under this assumption, `getDevice()` should return a simple *observing* pointer (observing pointers are pointers which do not keep the pointed object alive). The simplest kind of observing pointer is a raw pointer:

```
#include <memory>

class Device {
};

class Settings {
    std::unique_ptr<Device> device;
public:
    Settings(std::unique_ptr<Device> d) {
        device = std::move(d);
    }

    Device* getDevice() {
        return device.get();
    }
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Device> device(new Device());
    Settings settings(std::move(device));
    // ...
    Device *myDevice = settings.getDevice();
    // do something with myDevice...
}
```

[**NOTE 1:** *You may be wondering why I am using raw pointers here, when everybody keeps telling that raw pointers are bad, unsafe, and dangerous. Actually, that is a precious warning, but it is important to put it in the correct context: raw pointers are bad **when used for performing manual memory management**, i.e. allocating and deallocating objects through `new` and `delete`. When used purely as a means to achieve reference semantics and pass around non-owning, observing pointers, there is nothing intrinsically dangerous in raw pointers, except maybe for the fact that one should take care not to dereference a dangling pointer.* - **END NOTE 1**]

[**NOTE 2:** *As it emerged in the comments, in this particular case where the ownership is unique **and** the owned object is always guaranteed to be present (i.e. the internal data member `device` is never going to be `nullptr`), function `getDevice()` could (and maybe should) return a reference rather than a pointer. While this is true, I decided to return a raw pointer here because I meant this to be a short answer that one could generalize to the case where `device` could be `nullptr`, and to show that raw pointers are OK as long as one does not use them for manual memory management.* - **END NOTE 2**]

---

The situation is radically different, of course, if your `Settings` object should **not** have the exclusive ownership of the device. This could be the case, for instance, if the destruction of the `Settings` object should not imply the destruction of the pointed `Device` object as well.

This is something that only you as a designer of your program can tell; from the example you provide, it is hard for me to tell whether this is the case or not.

To help you figure it out, you may ask yourself whether there are any other objects apart from `Settings` that are entitled to keep the `Device` object alive as long as they hold a pointer to it, instead of being just passive observers. If that is indeed the case, then you need a **shared ownership policy**, which is what `std::shared_ptr` offers:

```
#include <memory>

class Device {
};

class Settings {
    std::shared_ptr<Device> device;
public:
    Settings(std::shared_ptr<Device> const& d) {
        device = d;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Device> getDevice() {
        return device;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Device> device = std::make_shared<Device>();
    Settings settings(device);
    // ...
    std::shared_ptr<Device> myDevice = settings.getDevice();
    // do something with myDevice...
}
```

Notice, that `weak_ptr` is an *observing* pointer, not an owning pointer - in other words, it does not keep the pointed object alive if all other owning pointers to the pointed object go out of scope.

The advantage of `weak_ptr` over a regular raw pointer is that you can safely tell whether `weak_ptr` is *dangling* or not (i.e. whether it is pointing to a valid object, or if the object originally pointed to has been destroyed). This can be done by calling the `expired()` member function on the `weak_ptr` object.

Comment: Thx a lot, thinking about the time of destruction was exactly what helped me to understand the different in usage. Also the note considering the raw pointer was very helpful. If I understand it correctly a `weak_ptr` would also be possible here (as both are observing pointers), but not necessary?

Comment: @LKK: Yes, correct. A `weak_ptr` is always an alternative to raw observing pointers. It is safer in a sense, because you could check if it is dangling before dereferencing it, but it also comes with some overhead. If you can easily guarantee that you are not going to dereference a dangling pointer, then you should be fine with observing raw pointers

Comment: @LKK, probably the easiest way to make sure that you won't dereference a dangling pointer is not to store it, or pass it to someone who will. Of course, you should also make sure that the owner isn't getting destroyed during the current scope, but this is easier to see since it's local. It's trickier in a multithreaded environment though.

Comment: In the first case it would probably even be better to let `getDevice()` return a reference, whouldn't it? So the caller would not have to check for `nullptr`.

Comment: @AndyProwl Regarding the first case, just make getDevice() return by reference. AFAIU, the Settings guarantees there must be a device attached, it's not optional. So, no use of pointers needed.

Comment: @vobject: In this case it could return a reference, yes, or a reference wrapper. However, this can't be generalized to the case where a returned pointer *could* be null, so I thought I'd just put a pointer in there (my main goal in this answer was to explain the meaning of observing pointers vs owning pointers in a generalized context, and to point out that raw pointers are not that bad when *observing* pointers are needed).

Comment: @vobject: Also, returning a reference would make it possible for the user to erroneously write something like: `Device myDevice = settings.getDevice();` when they actually meant `Device& myDevice = settings.getDevice();` (forgetting the `&`), which won't happen when returning a pointer. I also feel like checking against `nullptr` is not needed here, because the function is always guaranteed to return a valid pointer.

Comment: @AndyProwl and employing usage of `auto myDevice = settings.getDevice()` has potential of avoiding the mistake of forgetting the `&`.

Comment: @chico: Not sure what you mean. `auto myDevice = settings.getDevice()` will create a new instance of type `Device` called `myDevice` and copy-construct it from the one referenced by the reference that `getDevice()` returns. If you want `myDevice` to be a reference, you need to do `auto& myDevice = settings.getDevice()`. So unless I am missing something, we're back in the same situation we had without using `auto`.

Comment: @AndyProwl true, need to revise auto (and all the universal references stuff). I've expected auto to resolve to a reference type for the returning reference, my mistake.

Comment: @AndyProwl It seems likely in this example that `Device` should be non-copyable anyway (private copy constructor), which would avoid the issue with users accidentally writing `Devide myDevice = settings.getDevice()`.

Comment: Returning an observing raw pointer implies multiple responsibilities. The pointer semantics imply `nullptr` is a possible, and valid, result. It would only be through convention or explicit documentation that `nullptr` needn't be checked. I think a (`const`) reference should be the the choice by default, with an observing pointer as an alternative if you wish to also express that the type is optional.

Comment: Keep an eye on `std::optional` for possibly C++14, or check out `boost::optional` in order to fully express the right semantics. Also, a web search for `exempt_ptr` should return an ISO C++ proposal for a "dumb smart pointer" who's sole purpose is to express "observing pointer" semantics.

Comment: @BretKuhns: As I mentioned in a previous comment, it is true that in this case we could return a reference, but my goal in the answer was just to provide a simple solution that 1) could be generalized (applies also when the allowed pointer could be `null`), and 2) showed that raw pointers are bad only when used for manual memory management. But I agree that in this particular case we could/should return a reference.

Comment: @AndyProwl I Saw the earlier comments, but wanted to emphasize that returning the observing pointer in this case is misleading and doesn't convey the correct information to the caller. Earlier comments were more literal, whereas I'm speaking to the API and maintainability of the code.

Comment: I have a question: why not return a `std::unique_ptr<T>&` instead of a `T*`?

Comment: @Purrformance: Because you don't want to give away the ownership of the object - handing a modifiable `unique_ptr` to a client opens the possibility that the client will move from it, thus acquiring ownership and leaving you with a null (unique) pointer.

Comment: @Any Thank you, that makes sense. What about a `std::unique_ptr<T> const&`?

Comment: @Purrformance: While that would prevent a client from moving (unless the client is a mad scientist keen on `const_cast`s), I personally wouldn't do it. It exposes an implementation detail, i.e. the fact that ownership is unique and realized through a `unique_ptr`. I see things this way: if you want/need to pass/return ownership, pass/return a smart pointer (`unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`, depending on the kind of ownership). If you don't want/need to pass/return ownership, use a (properly `const`-qualified) pointer or reference, mostly depending on whether the argument can be null or not.

Comment: @AndyProwl If `Settings` has no interest in `Device` life (just uses it), is it correct to have a raw pointer as class field or is it anyway better a smart pointer?

Comment: @MarcoStramezzi Yes, in that case a raw pointer would be correct.

Comment: @AndyProwl: You recommend using a raw pointer/reference as getDevice() return type. Lets say Settings owns the Device. Also lets say I make a mistake by using getDevice() the wrong way, storing the returned raw pointer/reference longer than the Settings object lives. I would get a hard to debug undefined behavior. Could I use smart pointers to prevent that or at least make it easier to debug? I imagine using shared_ptr as member and as return value. I would need to throw an exception on destruction if the shared_ptr member does not hold the last reference. Is this feasible?

Comment: This answer is highly incomplete. For example, it does not mention all the implicit limitations you accept by choosing a `unique_ptr` over a `shared_ptr`, probably chief among them is the implicit deletion of the standard copy constructor, see [1]. Please thoroughly research the topic before posting an incomplete answer.

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030081/copy-constructor-for-a-class-with-unique-ptr

Answer (score 2):

```
class Device {
};

class Settings {
    std::shared_ptr<Device> device;
public:
    Settings(const std::shared_ptr<Device>& device) : device(device) {

    }

    const std::shared_ptr<Device>& getDevice() {
        return device;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Device> device(new Device());
    Settings settings(device);
    // ...
    std::shared_ptr<Device> myDevice(settings.getDevice());
    // do something with myDevice...
    return 0;
}
```

[`week_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) is used only for reference loops. The dependency graph must be acyclicdirected graph. In shared pointers there are 2 reference counts: 1 for [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)s, and 1 for all pointers (`shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr`). When all `shared_ptr`s are removed, the pointer is deleted. When pointer is needed from `weak_ptr`, `lock` should be used to get the pointer, if it exists.

Comment: So if I understand your answer correctly, smart pointers do replace raw pointers, but not necessarily references?

Comment: Are there actually *two* reference counts in a `shared_ptr`? Can you please explain why? As far as I understand, `weak_ptr` doesn't have to be counted because it simply creates a new `shared_ptr` when operating on the object (if the underlying object still exists).

Comment: @BjörnPollex: I created a short example for you: [link](http://store.naszta.hu/main/shrptr.h). I haven't implemented everything just the copy constructors and `lock`. [boost](http://boost.org) version is also thread safe on reference counting (`delete` is called only once).

Comment: @Naszta: Your example shows that it is *possible* to implement this using two reference counts, but your answer suggests that this is *required*, which I don't believe it is. Could you please clarify this in your answer?

Comment: @BjörnPollex: Look, this is the way how boost implementation does work. In boost atomic counters are used for thread safe. That's all. If you don't beleave me, you could easily check it in boost implementation (or in VS2012 its own).

Comment: @BjörnPollex, in order for `weak_ptr::lock()` to tell if the object has expired it must inspect the "control block" that contains the first reference count and pointer to the object, so the control block must not be destroyed while there are any `weak_ptr` objects still in use, so the number of `weak_ptr` objects must be tracked, which is what the second reference count does.  The object gets destroyed when the first ref count drops to zero, the control block gets destroyed when the second ref count drops to zero.