# Copy constructor for a class with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

How do I implement a copy constructor for a class that has a `unique_ptr` member variable? I am only considering C++11.

Comment: Well, what do you want the copy constructor to do?

Comment: I read that unique_ptr is uncopyable. This makes me wonder how do use a class that has a unique_ptr member variable in a `std::vector`.

Comment: I think after copy if we have 2 objects with unique pointers pointing to same location(object) then does that make sense? They should be unique. If a class with pointer implements copy constructor then that pointer should be shared pointer, I believe not an unique pointer.

Comment: @AbhijitKadam You can make a deep copy of the content of the unique_ptr. In fact, that's often the sensible thing to do.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Saw the soln by Daniel.

Comment: Please note that you are possibly asking the wrong question.  You probably do not want a copy constructor for your class containing a `unique_ptr`, you probably want a move constructor, if your goal is to put the data in a `std::vector`.  On the other hand, the C++11 standard has automatically created move constructors, so maybe you do want a copy constructor...

Comment: @codefx vector elements don't have to be copyable ; it just means that the vector won't be copyable.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Since the `unique_ptr` can not be shared, you need to either deep-copy its content or convert the `unique_ptr` to a `shared_ptr`.

```
class A
{
   std::unique_ptr< int > up_;

public:
   A( int i ) : up_( new int( i ) ) {}
   A( const A& a ) : up_( new int( *a.up_ ) ) {}
};

int main()
{
   A a( 42 );
   A b = a;
}
```

You can, as NPE mentioned, use a move-ctor instead of a copy-ctor but that would result in different semantics of your class. A move-ctor would need to make the member as moveable explicitly via `std::move`:

```
A( A&& a ) : up_( std::move( a.up_ ) ) {}
```

Having a complete set of the necessary operators also leads to

```
A& operator=( const A& a )
{
   up_.reset( new int( *a.up_ ) );
   return *this,
}

A& operator=( A&& a )
{
   up_ = std::move( a.up_ );
   return *this,
}
```

If you want to use your class in a `std::vector`, you basically have to decide if the vector shall be the unique owner of an object, in which case it would be sufficient to make the class moveable, but not copyable. If you leave out the copy-ctor and copy-assignment, the compiler will guide your way on how to use a std::vector with move-only types.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning move constructors?

Comment: @Daniel, isn't it the case that for C++11, I need to follow the rule of four meaning implement both copy-ctor and move-ctor?

Comment: +1, but the move constructor should be emphasized even more. In a comment, the OP says the goal is to use the object in a vector. For that, move construction and move assignment are the only things required.

Comment: @codefx No. `std::unique_ptr` itself is an example of a class that enables moving, but not copying.

Comment: If a class (does not have any `unique_ptr` member variable) has all 4 copy/move-ctor, copy/move-assignment, when is move-assignment used? My understanding was that move-ctor will be used for rvalues.

Comment: @codefx Yes, for rvalues. Examples of how to get rvalues are found in the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125632/when-does-move-constructor-get-called

Comment: Is there a resource leak in either of the copy/move assignment code snippet?

Comment: As a warning, the above strategy works for simple types like `int`.  If you have a `unique_ptr<Base>` that stores a `Derived`, the above will slice.

Comment: @Yakk and what kind of solution is applicable here ?

Comment: @bahti I might roll a `value_ptr` that uses a traits class to learn how to duplicate.

Comment: There's no check for null, so as-is this allows a nullptr dereference.  How about `A( const A& a ) : up_( a.up_ ? new int( *a.up_ ) : nullptr) {}`

Comment: In the small example provided, null can't happen, but it's worth mentioning for in general.

Comment: @RyanHaining In the general case you are correct. Of course, the `unique_ptr` is a private member in the above example (and in most real-world use-cases) and it depends on the class if an empty `unique_ptr` is valid or not.

Comment: @Yakk, the issue of the slicing of copies reminds me of the issue of deleters. A correctly-initialized `unique_ptr` needs to have the correct deleter type, and I guess this means something like `std::unique_ptr<Base, std::default_delete<Derived>>`. Might it be possible to extract the derived type from the deleter type, and therefore build a safer deep-copy?

Comment: @Aaron in polymorphic situations, the deleter will be type erased somehow, or pointless (if you know the type to delete, why change only the deleter?).  In any case, yes, this is the design of a `value_ptr` -- `unique_ptr` plus deleter/copier information.

Comment: (...continued from my comment 15 minutes ago) @Yakk, I've just noticed that there are constructors of `unique_ptr` that do take deleters - so they must be stored somewhere? Constructors (3) and (4) [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr)

Comment: @AaronMcDaid yes, you can pass in a stateful deleter.  The type of the `unique_ptr`'s deleter must be stateful, and in that case those constructors construct that deleter with state.  The default deleter has no state, and there is nothing to pass in for those two constructors (well, other than `{}`).  So you can create a stateful deleter for `unique_ptr`, but it won't be `std::default_delete<Derived>` (which has no state).  Stateless deleters are probably stored via the empty base optimization (assuming decent QOI).

Comment: Can `A(A&& a)` and `A& operator=(A&& a)` simply be `default` here?

Comment: @Nykakin Yes, I think so.

Comment: Caution with converting `unique_ptr` to `shared_ptr` to make your class copyable. You will almost certainly end up with a class that has broken semantics.

Answer (score 82):

The usual case for one to have a `unique_ptr` in a class is to be able to use inheritance (otherwise a plain object would often do as well, see RAII). For this case, *there is no appropriate answer in this thread up to now*.

**So, here is the starting point:**

```
struct Base
{
    //some stuff
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    //some stuff
};

struct Foo
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base> ptr;  //points to Derived or some other derived class
};
```

... and the goal is, as said, to make `Foo` copiable.

For this, one needs to do a *deep copy* of the contained pointer to ensure the derived class is copied correctly.

**This can be accomplished by adding the following code:**

```
struct Base
{
    //some stuff

    auto clone() const { return std::unique_ptr<Base>(clone_impl()); }
protected:
    virtual Base* clone_impl() const = 0;
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    //some stuff

protected:
    virtual Derived* clone_impl() const override { return new Derived(*this); };                                                 
};

struct Foo
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base> ptr;  //points to Derived or some other derived class

    //rule of five
    ~Foo() = default;
    Foo(Foo const& other) : ptr(other.ptr->clone()) {}
    Foo(Foo && other) = default;
    Foo& operator=(Foo const& other) { ptr = other.ptr->clone(); return *this; }
    Foo& operator=(Foo && other) = default;
};
```

There are basically two things going on here:

- The first is the addition of a user-defined copy constructor of `Foo`, This is necessary, as the `unique_ptr`-member iself has no copy constructor. In the declared copy-constructor, a new `unique_ptr` is created, and the pointer is set to a copy of the original pointee.
- In case inheritance is involved, the copy of the original pointee must be done carefully. The reason is that doing a simple copy via `std::unique_ptr<Base>(*ptr)` in the code above would result in slicing, i.e., only the base component of the object gets copied, while the derived part is missing.

  To avoid this, the copy has to be done via the clone-pattern. The
  idea is to do the copy through a virtual function `clone_impl()`
  which returns a `Base*` in the base class. In the derived class,
  however, it is extended via covariance to return a `Derived*`, and
  this pointer points to a newly created copy of the derived class. The
  base class can then access this new object via the base class pointer
  `Base*`, wrap it into a `unique_ptr`, and return it via the actual
  `clone()` function which is called from the outside.
- Second, by declaring a user-defined copy-constructor as done above, the move constructor gets deleted by the corresponding [C++ language rules](https://isocpp.org/blog/2018/02/quick-q-most-concise-way-to-disable-copy-and-move-semantics). The declaration via `Foo(Foo &&) = default` is thus just to let the compiler know that the standard move constructor still applies.

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer. Everyone else is going in circles in this thread, without hinting on why one would wish to copy an object pointed to by `unique_ptr` when direct containment would do otherwise. The answer??? **Inheritance**.

Comment: One may be using unique_ptr even when they know the concrete type being pointed to for a variety of reasons:
1. It needs to be nullable.
2. The pointee is very large and we might have limited stack space.

Often (1) and (2) will go together, hence one might on occasion prefer `unique_ptr` over `optional` for nullable types.

Comment: The pimple idiom is another reason.

Comment: What if a base class should not be abstract? Leaving it without pure-specifier can lead to run-time bugs if you forget reimplement it in derived.

Comment: @OleksijPlotnyc'kyj: yes, if you implement the `clone_impl` in base, the compiler won't tell you if you forget it in the derived class. You could, however, use another base class `Cloneable` and implement a pure virtual `clone_impl` there. Then the compiler will complain if you forget it in the derived class.

Comment: You can also override the clone function directly, without slicing or implementing clone_impl. Explicitly state the return type std::unique_ptr<Base> and return std::make_unique<Base>(*this) in Base and std::make_unique<Derived>(*this) ) in Derived. see Tyler D.'s post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060101/copy-constructor-of-a-class-containing-a-smart-pointer

Comment: @DanielFord: yes, you could, but then you could never clone a Derived. Think about multiple levels in an inheritance hierachy, for instance.

Comment: @davidhigh how would this fit in the following picture : `Foo` would not carry the `unique_ptr<Base>` anymore but would rather have a virtual "pimpled" getter of the unique pointer, and a derived `FooDerived` would carry a `unique_ptr<Derived>` with is own "typed" (i.e. returning a `unique_ptr<Derived>`) getter ? (I wrote "pimpled" because because pimpl would be needed for the getter as `unique_ptr` is not a covariant return type.)

Comment: @11house: maybe I do not completely understand your intent, but the idea here is that you only have a single `class Foo` that has a `unique_ptr`-member, and the question is how to make this class copyable. Sure you could add several things in derived classes, but this seems to be beyond the scope of this question -- maybe you ask a new one?

Comment: @davidhigh you are right. I posted here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/288017/race-condition-potentially-because-of-a-shared-pointer-unique-ptr-and-pimpl-and (as I have a have reasonably sized base code and commit) instead of SO, if that's fine with you.

Answer (score 17):

Try this helper to create deep copies, and cope when the source unique_ptr is null.

```
    template< class T >
    std::unique_ptr<T> copy_unique(const std::unique_ptr<T>& source)
    {
        return source ? std::make_unique<T>(*source) : nullptr;
    }
```

Eg:

```
class My
{
    My( const My& rhs )
        : member( copy_unique(rhs.member) )
    {
    }

    // ... other methods

private:
    std::unique_ptr<SomeType> member;
};
```

Comment: Will it correctly copy if source points to something derived from T?

Comment: @RomanShapovalov No, probably not, you would get slicing. In that case, the solution would probably be to add a virtual unique_ptr<T> clone() method to your T type, and provide overrides of the clone() method in types derived from T. The clone method would make a new instance of the derived type and return that.

Comment: Are there no unique/scoped pointers in c++ or boost libraries that has the deep copy functionality built in? It would be nice to not have to create our custom copy constructors etc. for classes that uses these smart pointers, when we want the deep copy behavior, which is often the case. Just wondering.

Answer (score 8):

Daniel Frey mention about copy solution,I would talk about how to move the unique_ptr

```
#include <memory>
class A
{
  public:
    A() : a_(new int(33)) {}

    A(A &&data) : a_(std::move(data.a_))
    {
    }

    A& operator=(A &&data)
    {
      a_ = std::move(data.a_);
      return *this;
    }

  private:
    std::unique_ptr<int> a_;
};
```

They are called move constructor and move assignment

you could use them like this

```
int main()
{
  A a;
  A b(std::move(a)); //this will call move constructor, transfer the resource of a to b

  A c;
  a = std::move(c); //this will call move assignment, transfer the resource of c to a

}
```

You need to wrap a and c by std::move because they have a name
std::move is telling the compiler to transform the value to
rvalue reference whatever the parameters are
In technical sense, std::move is analogy to something like "std::rvalue"

After moving, the resource of the unique_ptr is transfer to another unique_ptr

There are many topics that document rvalue reference; [this is a pretty easy one to begin with](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html).

Edit :

The moved object [shall remain valid but unspecified state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930105/does-moving-leave-the-object-in-a-usable-state).

C++ primer 5, ch13 also give a very good explanation about how to "move" the object

Comment: so what happens to object `a` after calling std::move(a) in the `b` move constructor? Is it just totally invalid?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest use make_unique

```
class A
{
   std::unique_ptr< int > up_;

public:
   A( int i ) : up_(std::make_unique<int>(i)) {}
   A( const A& a ) : up_(std::make_unique<int>(*a.up_)) {};

int main()
{
   A a( 42 );
   A b = a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As davdihigh mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43263477). One uses a `unique_ptr` mostly because of inheritance. Thus, most of the time you have a `std::unique_ptr<BaseType>` instead of `std::unique_ptr<ChildType>` (where `class ChildType : public BaseType {}`).
However, in order to create a `std::unique_ptr<BaseType>`, the `ChildType` is always directly involved at some point. You either pass a pointer to the `ChildType`, or a `unique_ptr<ChildType>` into the constructor.

There are situations where it's easier to switch the used `unique_ptr` class, than add a clone interface to all the Base- and ChildTypes that will be used at some point.

This enables one to write a wrapper around `unique_ptr` with a clone method (similar to the already existing custom deleter), like so:

```cpp
template<typename T>
requires (std::has_virtual_destructor_v<T>)
class clonable_unique_ptr {

public: // Associated types
    using pointer = std::unique_ptr<T>::pointer;
    using element_type = std::unique_ptr<T>::element_type;
    using cloner_type = std::function<T*(const T*)>;

private:
    std::unique_ptr<T> ptr;
    cloner_type cloneFn = [](const T*) { return nullptr; };

    clonable_unique_ptr(T* rawPtr, cloner_type cloneFn)
        : ptr(rawPtr), cloneFn(cloneFn) {}

public:
    constexpr clonable_unique_ptr() noexcept {}
    constexpr clonable_unique_ptr(std::nullptr_t) noexcept {}

    /**
     * ctor creating a clonable_unique_ptr from a given rawPtr.
     * @attention The rawPtr must be of the type that it actually points to!
     *            Meaning: The ChildType
     */
    template<typename U>
    explicit clonable_unique_ptr(U* rawPtr) : ptr(rawPtr) {
        static_assert(std::derived_from<U, T>, "Types not compatible");
        static_assert(!std::is_abstract_v<U>, "Entrypoint ctors need to be given the actual type, not the base type!");
        static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible_v<U>, "Type needs to be copy constructible");
        cloneFn = [](const T* ptr) { return new U(*static_cast<const U*>(ptr)); };
    }

    /**
     * ctor creating a clonable_unique_ptr from a given unique_ptr<ChildType>.
     * @attention The ptr must be of the type that it actually points to!
     *            Meaning: The ChildType
     */
    template<typename U>
    clonable_unique_ptr(std::unique_ptr<U>&& o) {
        static_assert(std::derived_from<U, T>, "Types not compatible");
        static_assert(!std::is_abstract_v<U>, "Entrypoint ctors need to be given the actual type, not the base type!");
        static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible_v<U>, "Type needs to be copy constructible");
        cloneFn = [](const T* ptr) { return new U(*static_cast<const U*>(ptr)); };
        ptr = std::move(o);
    }

    /**
     * move ctor, moving from another instance of clonable_unique_ptr
     */
    clonable_unique_ptr(clonable_unique_ptr&& o)
        : ptr(std::move(o.ptr)), cloneFn(std::move(o.cloneFn)) {}

    /** move assignable */
    clonable_unique_ptr& operator=(clonable_unique_ptr&&) = default;


    // default unique_ptr interface with accessors
    T* get() const noexcept { return ptr.get(); }
    T* operator->() { return ptr.get(); }
    auto& operator*() const noexcept(noexcept(*std::declval<pointer>())) {
        return *ptr;
    }
    void reset() noexcept {
        ptr.reset();
        cloneFn = [](const T*) { return nullptr; };
    }
    void swap(clonable_unique_ptr& o) noexcept {
        ptr.swap(o.ptr);
        std::swap(cloneFn, o.cloneFn);
    }

    /**
     * Clone the instance of T contained in this pointer by using the copy ctor
     * of the ChildType that is contained in this ptr.
     */
    clonable_unique_ptr<T> clone() const {
        return clonable_unique_ptr(cloneFn(get()), cloneFn);
    }
};


template<typename T0, typename T1>
bool inline operator==(const clonable_unique_ptr<T0>& ptr0, const clonable_unique_ptr<T1>& ptr1) {
    return ptr0.get() == ptr1.get();
}
template<typename T0>
bool inline operator==(const clonable_unique_ptr<T0>& ptr0, std::nullptr_t) {
    return ptr0.get() == nullptr;
}
```

Like this, the responsibility of implementing the `clone` was pushed into the pointer and out of BaseClass/ChildClass.
Some examples:

```cpp
struct BaseClass {
    virtual void doStuff() = 0;
    virtual ~BaseClass() {}
};

struct ChildClass : public BaseClass {
    std::string value;
    ChildClass(std::string value) : value(value) {}
    void doStuff() override {
        std::cout << "doStuff: " << value << " " << this << std::endl;
    }
};
```

The `clonable_unique_ptr` can then be created using either a pointer to `ChildType`:

```cpp
clonable_unique_ptr<BaseClass> fromPtr(new ChildClass("cake"));
clonable_unique_ptr<BaseClass> fromPtrClone = fromPtr.clone();
fromPtr->doStuff(); // two different instances
fromPtrClone->doStuff();
```

or from a `std::unique_ptr<ChildType>` for easier compatibility:

```cpp
clonable_unique_ptr<BaseClass> fromUPtr = std::make_unique<ChildClass>("blub");
clonable_unique_ptr<BaseClass> fromUPtrClone = fromUPtr.clone();
fromUPtr->doStuff(); // two different instances
fromUPtrClone->doStuff();
```

[Here is a link to Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/6ns16WcYd) to toy with it. I didn't add custom deleter support to this wrapper yet, because I personally don't need it, but that should be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

`unique_ptr` is not copyable, it is only moveable.

This will directly affect Test, which is, in your second, example also only moveable and not copyable.

In fact, it is good that you use `unique_ptr` which protects you from a big mistake.

For example, the main issue with your first code is that the pointer is never deleted which is really, really bad. Say, you would fix this by:

```
class Test
{
    int* ptr; // writing this in one line is meh, not sure if even standard C++

    Test() : ptr(new int(10)) {}
    ~Test() {delete ptr;}
};

int main()
{       
     Test o;
     Test t = o;
}
```

This is also bad. What happens, if you copy `Test`? There will be two classes that have a pointer that points to the same address.

When one `Test` is destroyed, it will also destroy the pointer. When your second `Test` is destroyed, it will try to remove the memory behind the pointer, as well. But it has already been deleted and we will get some bad memory access runtime error (or undefined behavior if we are unlucky).

So, the right way is to either implement copy constructor and copy assignment operator, so that the behavior is clear and we can create a copy.

`unique_ptr` is way ahead of us here. It has the semantic meaning: "**I am `unique`, so you cannot just copy me.**" So, it prevents us from the mistake of now implementing the operators at hand.

You can define copy constructor and copy assignment operator for special behavior and your code will work. But you are, rightfully so (!), forced to do that.

The moral of the story: always use `unique_ptr` in these kind of situations.

Comment: why is using a unique_ptr the moral of the story?

Comment: Because of what is described in the whole remainder of the answer