# C++11 copying std::vector of std::unique_ptr which is a member

Tags: c++11, vector, copy-constructor, unique-ptr

I have a class `graph` which has a member:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<layer>> _layers;
```

I understand that the nature of `std::unique_ptr` is to be non-copyable.
My `graph::graph(const graph & rhs);` copy constructor produces a compilation error, because my ordinary implementation violates the nature of `std::unique_ptr`.

```
graph::graph(const graph & rhs)
: _layers(rhs._layers) {}
```

If I do a `std::move` then I will be violating the **constness** of param `rhs`, which is not what I want.
I know I can make deep copies (e.g., create new unique pointers for each object stored in `rhs._layers`) but is there some elegant way of doing this, other than iterating each item in `rhs._layers` and allocating a new unique pointer?

gcc/g++ is c++11 not c++14

My current solution is deep copying the objects and allocating new pointers:

```
graph::graph(const graph & rhs)
{
   for (const auto & ptr : rhs._layers)
       _layers.emplace_back(std::unique_ptr<layer>(new layer(*ptr)));
}
```

Comment: This had already been discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030081/copy-constructor-for-a-class-with-unique-ptr

Comment: Uneducated guess: Would this be a good use case for `weak_ptr`s having a view to `shared_ptr`s?

Comment: @Katana314 I don't know TBH, but those pointers are not to be seen or accessed outside the  class. I don't mind copying objects (hence the deep copy). What would the advantages of `weak_ptr` be in this scenario?

Comment: @Alex Unlike a shared_ptr, that `_layers` variable would still be the owning reference to the actual `layer`s. If it's destroyed, the objects are destroyed. The disadvantage is, each access of `layer` from a `weak_ptr` would need to be inside a conditional statement to confirm the layer has not yet been destroyed. Also, there is no more compiler guarantee that the previously-unique pointer is not getting copied into another shared_ptr (so it would be up to you to safeguard it).

Comment: @Katana314 that actually makes sense, I don't know how I would implement it though. Care to provide a small example?

Comment: If you don't want move semantics, perhaps unique_ptr is not the best choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most elegant solution would use the STL:

```
graph::graph(const graph & rhs)
{
    _layers.reserve(rhs._layers.size());
    std::transform(
        std::begin(rhs._layers),
        std::end(rhs._layers),
        std::back_inserter(_layers),
        [](const std::unique_ptr<layer>& uptr) {
            return std::unique_ptr<layer>{uptr ? new layer{*uptr} : nullptr};
        });
}
```

---

[`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter)

Comment: Don't have c++14, and this is identical to what I'm already doing. I guess I need template specialization for my type.

Comment: @Alex STL should be preferred to raw loops, but yes this is identical.  Updated with a c++11 friendly version.

Comment: @BrianRodriguez  If I have other members of class, I should copy this all in this copy-constructor. Right?

Comment: @Max yep, each `std::unique_ptr` collection in your class should have these same 2 function calls made on them.

Answer (score 1):

You can also review the possibility to use the vector of std::shared_ptr instead of std::unique, in this case you can avoid real copying

Comment: having shared_ptr means that others can modify the objects, does it not?

Comment: @Alex Not if they are: `std:: shared_ptr<const layer>`.  I agree that this is most likely the behavior you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a copy but you can make a move constructor:

```
graph::graph(graph && rhs)
```

You should be able to move the `_layers` vector in there and then you should be able to move `graph` instances.

If this is not what you want then you will have to abandon the use of `unique_ptr` or add a layer of indirection to the `_layers` vector if that can be shared among graph instances.

*Edit:* An alternative solution would be to not use pointers in the vector at all but emplace the instances into the vector directly. This way the vector would be copied with all the contents naturally.

Comment: this violates the whole point of having a const object parameter. Besides I am not interested in *moving* but *copying*.

Comment: @Alex then you should not be using `std::unique_ptr` in the first place. Is there a reason you are using a pointer here at all? Could you just emplace the instances in the vector?