# Copying a std::unique_ptr of an interface

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I need to copy a `std::unique_ptr<Interface>` of some interface `Interface`.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030081/copy-constructor-for-a-class-with-unique-ptr) sums it nice up, but it doesn't work in my case, because `Interface` doesn't have an available constructor.

Example:

```
//Pointer to copy
std::unique_ptr<Interface> ptr = std::make_unique<Interface>();

//error: incomplete type is not allowed
std::unique_ptr<Interface> copy{ new Interface(*ptr.get().data) };
```

Is there a way to deep copy `ptr` to `copy`?

Comment: what is the definition of `Interface`?

Comment: What do you mean _"I need to copy"_? `std::unique_ptr` isn't copyable by purpose. If you want a new instance of the interface, create a new one.

Comment: @JohnSmith I'd suspect something abstract.

Comment: @JohnSmith It's from a library, so I don't know, sorry

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have it as a member variable of a class, and I would like to have that class be copyable.

Comment: Find out. We can't help you without knowing what your code does.

Comment: If `Interface` supports copy, you can create a new `unique_ptr` to the copied object. Otherwise no copy....

Comment: If your class is not copyable, hiding it behind a unique_ptr isn't going to suddenly magically make it copyable.

Comment: Voted to close as unclear, because it's really unclear. In particular `Interface` isn't specified, and code ownership isn't specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem with your `Interface` class, not `unique_ptr`. Your `Interface` class cannot be constructed based on dereferencing the return value of `Interface::data`.

Presumably, `Interface` is copy-constructible and non-polymorphic. If it is, you would simply copy construct it: `make_unique<Interface>(*ptr)`. And if it's not copy-constructible, then you can't copy `Interface` at all. If it is a polymorphic type, then you have no ability to copy it correctly, unless the type is expressly coded to permit such things.

Comment: **−1** "If [the interface is copy constructible], you would simply copy construct it: make_unique<Interface>(\*ptr)" tells the OP to use a technical loophole that he fails to understand is that, to *slice* the object he wants to copy. Very ungood advice.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Added note about polymorphic types.

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
virtual std::unique_ptr<Interface> clone() const = 0;
```

To `Interface`.  Implement it in the final class of interface's implementation with:

```
virtual std::unique_ptr<Interface> clone() const override final {
  return std::make_unique<Implementation>(*this);
}
```

Comment: I guess that would be possible, but `Interface` is from a library, and I can't modify it. Thanks though

Comment: Also, there's really no reason to make that a member function. It's just as easy to write a `unique_ptr_clone` function that will clone any `T` that is copy-constructible.

Comment: @NicolBolas: No, the function needs to be virtual. A separate function would just slice the object.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Or you SFINAE protect it against polymorphic types, just as you would against non-copy-constructible types.

Comment: @NicolBolas: No, this is an ["interface" class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28computing%29#Software_interfaces_in_object-oriented_languages). I linked that to Wikipedia's article about it.

Comment: @rakete without the unique_ptr, how would you copy a pointer to interface?  What does it mean to cooy it?  How did you create it?  Who wrapped it in a unique_ptr?  These can lead to a different solution.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: No, it's a class *named* `Interface`.

Comment: Because it's a pointer I can copy it, the library exposes raw pointers, and I'm wrapping them in smart pointers. (Maybe I missinterpreted the name "Interface", isn't that what's it called, a non-default constructible class, that can only be constructed through factory instances?)

Comment: @rake copying the pointer to `Interface` does not copy the `Interface`.  You get two pointers to the *same* instance of `Interface`.  A `unique_ptr<Interface>` considers itself *owning* that object, with unique power and resonsibility to delete the object.

Comment: Yes I know that :)

Comment: @rake then what are you asking?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to copy the type (even though it was straightforward) in a unique ptr to another one

Comment: @rake but a unique_ptr claims unique and sole ownership.  Copy that makes little sense; how can two smart pointers both have unique and sole ownership of the same object?  Are you aware of `std::move`?

Comment: Yes, but then I would have to move every time I use the class, and that would be a lot

Comment: @rake everytime you transfer ownership from one pointer to another from a non-expiring value, yes?

Comment: @rake You claim "every time you use the class", but you only have to move when you want to transfer ownership in a situation where a move does not automatically happen.  You claim to understand move, unique ptr ownership rules, and pointer ownership rules, and I have no idea why you are still confused.  Probably because you do not uderstand these things...

Comment: I didn't mean that literally, but the thing is, I would like to copy the class fully, without moving ownership of the pointers involved. That's why I asked, because I couldn't figure out how to copy that class that is in a unique pointer. But you're right, I don't understand move semantics and ownership a lot

Comment: @NicolBolas: The OP says it's "some interface Interface". Your idea that it's a class that just by happenchance is named `Interface`, is stupid as a way to rescue your position. At this point I do not believe it's still a misunderstanding on your part.