# Deep Clone for a unique_ptr which point to a base class

Tags: c++, constructor, abstract-class, unique-ptr

The problem is: How can I do the deep clone for a unique_ptr which point to a base class, and the base class has some virtual functions.

The detail code:

```
class QueryRewrite {
public:
     QueryRewrite(bool wasRes, ReturnMeta rmeta, const KillZone &kill_zone, 
                  AbstractQueryExecutor *const executor)
         : rmeta(rmeta), kill_zone(kill_zone),
           executor(std::unique_ptr<AbstractQueryExecutor>(executor)) {}
     QueryRewrite(const QueryRewrite &other_qr)
         : rmeta(other_qr.rmeta), kill_zone(other_qr.kill_zone),
           executor(other_qr.executor.get()) {}
     QueryRewrite(){}
     QueryRewrite(QueryRewrite &&other_qr) : rmeta(other_qr.rmeta),
           executor(std::move(other_qr.executor)) {}
     const ReturnMeta rmeta;
     const KillZone kill_zone;
     std::unique_ptr<AbstractQueryExecutor> executor;
};
```

In the copy constructor

```
QueryRewrite(const QueryRewrite &other_qr)
         : rmeta(other_qr.rmeta), kill_zone(other_qr.kill_zone),
           executor(other_qr.executor.get()) {}
```

`executor(other_qr.executor.get())` is just a shallow copy to the executor, if I want to do the deep copy, how to change the code?

And `executor` is a unique_ptr which point to an instance of `AbstractQueryExecutor`, the `AbstractQueryExecutor` is a base class which has some virtual functions, so if I change the code to 
`executor(new AbstractQueryExecutor(other_qr.executor.get()))`, it will say something like:

```
 error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘AbstractQueryExecutor’
 note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘AbstractQueryExecutor’:
```

Comment: C introduced `unique_ptr` and all the foundation required to make them work!? Cool!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030081/copy-constructor-for-a-class-with-unique-ptr

Comment: The `unique_ptr` is not really related to the issue. This is the classic problem of polymorphic copy, normally solved by a virtual `clone()` member function.

Comment: `executor(other_qr.executor.get())` isn't a shallow copy, it creates a pointer that two different `unique_ptr`s both think they uniquely own.  Which isn't good.

Answer (score 0):

Write a `value_ptr` which inherits from a `unique_ptr`, but on copy construct/assigning invokes `unique_ptr<T> T::clone() const` on non-null `T*` to clone.

The use that.

```
template<class T, class D=std::default_delete<T>>
struct value_ptr:std::unique_ptr<T,D>{
  using base=std::unique_ptr<T,D>;
  using base::base;
  value_ptr()=default;
  value_ptr(value_ptr&&)=default;
  value_ptr& operator=(value_ptr&&)=default;
  value_ptr(base&& o):base(std::move(o)){}
  value_ptr(value_ptr const&o):
    value_ptr( o?value_ptr(o->clone()):value_ptr() )
  {}
  value_ptr& operator=(value_ptr const&o){
    value_ptr tmp(o);
    *this=std::move(tmp);
    return *this;
  }
};
```

That should do it.  Code not tested.

The abstract base needs to have a `virtual std::unique_ptr<AbstractBase> clone()const` added, and derived need to implement, for the above to work.

Also follow the rule of zero; once you have a value ptr, you can `=default` or sometimes skip the copy/move ctors/assigns of enclosing classes.

As an aside, consider copy on write instead of deep copy.