# Constructor deleted in unique_ptr

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

Was reading more about smart pointers and came across the concept of  constructor getting deleted when you copy one unique_ptr to another. What exactly is that concept?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>

class Person {
  public:
  int e;
  Person(int e) : e(e) { }
};

int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<Person> p (new Person(5));
  // Below line seems to be deleting constructor and thus error in compiling.
  std::unique_ptr<Person> q  = p;
}
```

std::move semantics are working fine though.

Comment: What do you want to know? `std::unique_ptr` can be moved but not copied, because it's *unique*.

Comment: Aah. Missed this tiny detail.

Comment: A solution to this is already discssed in this:
[Copy constructor for a class with unique_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030081/copy-constructor-for-a-class-with-unique-ptr)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since a unique pointer should be unique,  it cannot be copied.  It can only be moved.

Hence, the copy constructor is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Normal copy semantics will result in both `q` and `p` holding a pointer to the same `Person` object and both their destructors will then `delete` the same object.

That's invalid. You should delete the same allocation exactly once.

Move semantics however are permitted to modify the object being copied. In the case of `std::unique_ptr<>` the object is set to "empty" (i.e. assigned `nullptr`).

Answer (score 0):

The `unique_ptr` class:

> The class satisfies the requirements of MoveConstructible and
> MoveAssignable, but of neither CopyConstructible nor CopyAssignable.

The copy constructor and copy assignment operator do not work in the case of unique_ptr. The unique_ptr holds the ownership exclusively. It cannot be shared.

[https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr](https://Refence%20for%20unique_ptr%20documentation)

Answer (score 0):

copy construtor and copy assignment operator are deleted. So, unique pointer can't copy and assign to other object.