# Is it necessary to use a unique_ptr in this case?

Tags: c++, pointers

So, here is an example of a class I'm creating :

```
typedef struct st{
    int counter;
    int fields[128];
}stEx;

class Foo {
    stEx *E;
    int index;
public : 
    Foo(){
        this->index = 0;
        this->E = new stEx;
    }
    ~Foo(){
        delete E;
    }
}
```

Since I want E to be the instance of the Foo object alone, the E object has to be destroyed automatically when the Foo object gets destroyed, and should'nt therefore outlive that object. That's how I came across the notion of smart pointers, and unique pointers in particular.

However, I can't seem to understand why I need to use unique pointers. 
And how do I destroy/free a unique pointer?

Here is my attempt with unique pointers.

```
#include <memory>

typedef struct st{
    int counter;
    int fields[128];
}stEx;

class Foo {
    std::unique_ptr<stEx> E;
    int index;
public : 
    Foo(){
        this->index = 0;
        this->E = std::unique_ptr<stEx>(new stEx());
    }
    ~Foo(){
        E.release; // ?
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using `release` would defeat the purpose. The purpose of a `unique_ptr` is to remove the burden to remember to free the resource. [`std::unique_ptr::release`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release) does the opposite, calling it is a statement that you do **not** want the object to be automatically deleted.

Comment: Consider using `std::make_unique<stEx>()` instead of using `new`.

Comment: Why are you even using a pointer here? Why not make it a normal value member of the class and you then get automatic cleanup.

Comment: Try copy constructing or assigning a `Foo` object.

Comment: If you want to copy construct Foo: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030081/copy-constructor-for-a-class-with-unique-ptr

Comment: There is a big difference between "necessary" and "good style".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And how do I destroy/free a unique pointer?

You don't. That's the whole point of `unique_ptr`: `Foo::E` is destructed along with `Foo`, and destructs its pointee too. No manual cleanup.

Also, you will almost never have to use `release`. This function makes the `unique_ptr` release its pointee, in the sense that it *won't* destroy it, and you'll have to `delete` it yourself as before.

Answer (score 7):

The idiomatic way to do this would be:

```
class Foo
{
    std::unique_ptr<stEx> E;
    int index;
public: 
    Foo() : E(std::make_unique<stEx>()), index(0)
    {}
};
```

- use initialization list
- use make_unique (never type `new`)
- don't have a destructor

This type will automatically be move-enabled, but copy-disabled

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I can't see the need to use `unique_ptr`, because you have only one object, and the life time of it is within the life time of the class, so you can use just a member.

```
typedef struct st{
    int counter;
    int fields[128];
}stEx;

class Foo {
    stEx E;
    int index;
public : 
    Foo(){
        index = 0;
    }
}
```

Also you don't need to use the pointer this to access to the class members.

And there is no need to call:

```
E.release; // ?
```

The memory allocated with this line:

```
this->E = std::unique_ptr<stEx>(new stEx());
```

Plus the overhead of the smart pointer handle, is freed when the smart pointer goes our of scope.

In your case is implicitly in `Foo` destructor.

Note: `unique_ptr::release()` Releases the ownership of the managed object 
If you need that the `new stEx` object be no longer owned by `E`.
You have to:

```
Foo* stExPtr = up.release(); //stEx is no longer owned by unique_ptr
delete stExPtr;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the destructor, the compiler will automatically insert calls the destructors for all non-static members of the class. So you don't have to add any code for that to happen.