# How to clone class with vector of unique_ptr to base class

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <map>

class IOutput{
public:
    virtual std::ostream& print(std::ostream& out) const = 0;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<IOutput> clone() const = 0;
    virtual ~IOutput() = default;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const IOutput& ser) {
    ser.print(out);
    return out;
}

class String : public IOutput {
private:
    std::string m_str;
public:
    String( std::string str )
        : m_str(std::move(str))
    {}
    std::ostream& print(std::ostream& out) const override {
        out << m_str;
        return out;
    }
    std::unique_ptr<IOutput> clone() const override { return std::make_unique<String>(*this); }
};

class List : public IOutput {
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IOutput>> m_elements;
public:
    std::ostream& print(std::ostream& out) const override {

    }
    std::unique_ptr<IOutput> clone() const override {
        return std::make_unique<List>(*this); 
    } 
};




int main () {
    String s {"string s"};
    String s2 {"string s2"};
    String s3 {"string s3"};
    String s4 {"string s4"};


    return 0;
}
```

**Error**

```
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_construct.h:75: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = IOutput; _Dp = std::default_delete<IOutput>]’
 { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I found out that this error occurs only if I have  `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IOutput>>` in `List` . It looks like I am copying that vector when I am calling `std::make_unique<List>(*this)` in **clone** , which means it has to copy each element from that vector, which in our case (unique_ptr) is forbidden.
How to solve this?

Comment: you can't copy a unique_ptr. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030081/copy-constructor-for-a-class-with-unique-ptr for more information

Comment: When cloning a vector of unique pointers, you need to explicitly go over the original vector, clone each element, and push the result to the target vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler cannot generate a copy constructor, because the vector member is non-copyable. If you wish to support copying, you need to implement it yourself, for instance:

```
List(List const& other) : m_elements(other.m_elements.size()) {
    std::transform(begin(other.m_elements), end(other.m_elements), begin(m_elements),
      [](std::unique_ptr<IOutput> const& o_ptr) {
        return o_ptr->clone();
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: An interesting case where the [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution without `std::transform`

```
List(const List& other)
{
    m_elements.reserve(other.m_elements.size());
    for (const auto& x: other.m_elements) {
        m_elements.emplace_back(x->clone());
    }
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: the `const` for `x` is *optional* - as elements in the vector are const, `x` will be const anyway (because of being reference!), no matter if explicitly declared as or not... But id does not disturb either.

Answer (score 0):

`IOutput` has a `clone()` member function. You should make a new `List` that contains clones of the elements of the vector.