# Copy constructor of a class containing a smart pointer

Tags: c++, oop, unique-ptr, rule-of-three

In the following example we have a class `Class` that contains a `Bridge` object that takes care of all the memory handling for us (rule of three).

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() {};
    virtual Base* clone() const = 0;
    virtual ~Base() {};
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() {};
    virtual Base* clone() const {
        return new Derived(*this);
    }
    virtual ~Derived() {}
};

class Bridge {
public:
    Bridge(const Bridge& bridge_) {
        base = bridge_.base->clone();
    }
    Bridge(const Base& base_) {
        base = base_.clone();
    }
    ~Bridge() { delete base; }
    
    Bridge& operator=(const Bridge& assignFrom) {
        if(this != &assignFrom) {
            delete base;
            base = assignFrom.base->clone();
        }
        return *this;
    }
private:
    Base *base;
};

class Class {
public:
    Class(const Bridge& bridge_) : bridge(bridge_) {};
private:
    Bridge bridge;
};

int main()
{
    Derived derived;
    Class c(derived);
    Class c1(c);  
}
```

Now, I have just learned about smart pointers and was trying to recreate the above example using `unique_ptr`. To my understanding, we basically don't need to implement the rule of 3 ourselves as the smart pointer contains it already. To test this, I made the following example:

```
class BaseSMRT {
public:
    BaseSMRT() {};
    virtual std::unique_ptr<BaseSMRT> clone() const = 0;
    virtual ~BaseSMRT() {};
};

class DerivedSMRT : public BaseSMRT {
public:
    DerivedSMRT() {};
    virtual std::unique_ptr<BaseSMRT> clone() const {
        return std::make_unique<DerivedSMRT>(*this);
    }
    virtual ~DerivedSMRT() {}
};

class ClassSMRT {
public:
    ClassSMRT(const BaseSMRT& base) {
        ptr = base.clone();
    };
private:
    std::unique_ptr<BaseSMRT> ptr;
};

int main()
{
    DerivedSMRT derivedSMRT;
    ClassSMRT cSMRT(derivedSMRT);
    ClassSMRT cSMRT2(cSMRT); // error: Call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'ClassSMRT'
}
```

As you can see in the above example, initialising `cSMRT2` with `cSMRT` through the copy constructor doesn't work and gives me the above error.

I don't get this: Why is it that I can call `Class`'s default copy constructor like this, `Class c1(c);`, but not call `ClassSMRT`'s default copy constructor, `ClassSMRT cSMRT2(cSMRT);`?

This suggests that the rule of three isn't already implemented for us when we are using `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Please be more specific than "doesn't work".

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is non-copyable. It doesn't have a copy constructor that makes a copy of the object that is held by `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @Evg Thanks - so you are telling me that the rule of 3 is not implemented for us when using `std::unique_ptr`? I would still have to implement it myself? In that case, I can't see what the usage is of `std::unique_ptr` is in this particular case

Comment: For `unique_ptr` it is a rule of 5, but copy operations are deleted. If you want to copy an object, you should do it yourself. It would be semantically wrong for a smart pointer to make such a copy - after all, it is just a pointer.

Comment: I find that it helps to think of `unique_ptr` not as a pointer, but as a unique *object* – it can't be copied, it can only be moved.

Comment: smart pointers prevent your program from going horribly wrong unexpectedly when you violate the rule of 3/5, you still might need to implement them in order to get your desired behaviour

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks! If I was to make my example work then, is all I have to do simply to use `std::move` in the clone?

Comment: @TylerD No, you need to follow the rule of 3/5 in `ClassSMRT`. You need to define what copying an object that has a non-copyable member means in your particular case.

Answer (score 2):

`unique_ptr` is designed to stop accidental copies. You want to implicitly clone you polymorphic type when copied. `unique_ptr` doesn't (directly) fit your uses.

I would suggest a rename of `Bridge`

```
template </*Cloneable*/ typename T>
class clone_ptr {
public:
    clone_ptr(const T& base_) 
      : base(base_.clone()) {}
    clone_ptr(const clone_ptr& other)
      : base(other.base->clone()) {}
    clone_ptr(clone_ptr&& other) = default;
    
    clone_ptr& operator=(clone_ptr other) {
        base = std::move(other.base);
        return *this;
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<T> base;
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't `operator=` take `clone_ptr` by const-ref?

Comment: @Evg taking by value covers move and copy, if I implemented it how I intended. I blame a lack of coffee atm

Comment: Taking by value with a move is a nice solution.