# move constructor and move assignment

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this code

```
class GameViewModel
{
public:
    GameViewModel(PlayerData& playerData, std::unique_ptr<WeaponData> WeaponData) : m_playerData(playerData), m_WeaponData(std::move(WeaponData)){}

    PlayerData& GetPlayerData() const { return m_playerData; }
    // I want to do:
    //void SetPlayerData(PlayerData playerData) { m_playerData = playerData); }
    WeaponData& GetWeaponData() const { return *m_WeaponData; }
    
    bool IsVisible() const;
    int GetColour() const { return m_playerData.m_Envelope.GetColour(); }

private:
    PlayerData& m_playerData;
    std::unique_ptr<WeaponData> m_WeaponData;
};
```

I'd like to update the member variable m_playerData, (see SetPlayerData) but I get a C2280 attempting to ref a deleted function. I need to define my own move constructor and move assignment. I've looked at:
[Copy constructor for a class with unique_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030081/copy-constructor-for-a-class-with-unique-ptr)
but how do I initialize m_playerData in the move constructor?

Comment: You can't set references. Full stop, end of story. If you want to be able to set it, you should consider changing the reference into a pointer (`PlayerData*`)

Comment: Or a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr<PlayerData>` or `std::shared_ptr<PlayerData>`. Perhaps you can clarify why you wanted `m_playerData` to be a reference instead of a pointer like `m_weaponData` so that we can advise you better.

Comment: btw error codes are compiler specific, you should include the compiler error message

Comment: and thank you @CompuChip, yes that's probably the best way, the use of a smart pointer.

Comment: Smart pointers are not automatically better. If a player quits the game but the GameViewModel stays, do you really want the GameViewModel to keep the player around? (as opposed to probably causing a crash, so you notice the bug and fix it)

Comment: @user253751 The same would happen without a smart pointer. If you aren't explicitly deleting it, a new'd object would also "hang around". Not using a smart pointer doesn't buy you anything in that scenario you described. And there is nothing wrong with explicitly deleting or releasing a smart pointer, so it still seems the better choice.

Comment: Another option is a `std::reference_wrapper`

Comment: @Taekahn presumably you would delete the PlayerData when the player quits the game

Comment: @user253751 yea….which you can do with a smart pointer or a raw one.

Comment: @Taekahn the GameViewModel does not own the PlayerData. If you accidentally leave the GameViewModel around it probably shouldn't cause the PlayerData to stick around.

Comment: @user253751 exactly the reason _to_ use smart pointers. `player*` says nothing about ownership. It may or may not own it. Smart pointers explicitly delineate ownership. I have nothing against raw pointers, but I see no reason to use them outside of specific scenarios when there are better alternatives. But comments aren’t the place for discussion so I guess we’ll just have to disagree.

Comment: @Taekahn What's the smart pointer that says you don't own something?

Comment: Shared_ptr. Random link https://george3d6.medium.com/being-smart-about-ownership-5ba2569a3ed7