Use of deleted function std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&)
I am currently trying to set up a very basic Entity Component System.
For this, I have defined the following classes:
class Component
{
public:
    virtual ~Component() {};  // Ensure polymorphic behavior with a virtual destructor
};

class TransformComponent : public Component
{
    glm::vec2 position = {0.0f, 0.0f};
    float rotation = 0.0f;
    float scale = 1.0f;
};

using identifier =  uuids::uuid;
class Entity {
private:
    identifier id;
    bool isActive = true;
    std::string name = "new entity";

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>> components;
public:
    Entity() : isActive(true), id( UUID::get()), name("NEW") {};
    ~Entity() = default;

    // Disable copying
    Entity(const Entity&) = delete;
    Entity& operator=(const Entity&) = delete;

    // Define move constructor and move assignment
    Entity(Entity&& other) noexcept;
    Entity& operator=(Entity&& other) noexcept;

    template<typename T>
    T* GetOrAdd() {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value, "T must be derived from Component");
        for (auto& comp : components) {
            if (auto result = dynamic_cast<T*>(comp.get())) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        auto newComp = std::make_unique<T>();
        T* result = newComp.get();
        components.push_back(std::move(newComp));
        return result;
    }

When I try to add an Entity to another class as a std::unique_ptr like this:
class Scene {
        public:
            Scene(std::string sceneName, bool isEditorMode);
            ~Scene();
        private: 
            std::unique_ptr<Entity> ent = std::make_unique<Entity>();
}

I get the following errors:
D:\Projects\searchengineproject\vocabulary\game\src\rendering\HierarchyPanel.cpp: In constructor 'gl3::HierarchyPanel::HierarchyPanel()':
D:\Projects\searchengineproject\vocabulary\game\src\rendering\HierarchyPanel.cpp:9:52: error: use of deleted function 'gl3::Scene& gl3::Scene::operator=(const gl3::Scene&)'
    9 |         currentScene = *GlobalHelper::GetScenes()[0];
      |                                                    ^
In file included from D:\Projects\searchengineproject\vocabulary\game\src\rendering\HierarchyPanel.h:4,
                 from D:\Projects\searchengineproject\vocabulary\game\src\rendering\HierarchyPanel.cpp:1:
D:/Projects/searchengineproject/vocabulary/game/src/entities/Scene.h:21:11: note: 'gl3::Scene& gl3::Scene::operator=(const gl3::Scene&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   21 |     class Scene {
      |           ^~~~~
D:/Projects/searchengineproject/vocabulary/game/src/entities/Scene.h:21:11: error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = gl3::Entity; _Dp = std::default_delete<gl3::Entity>]'
In file included from D:/Program Files/CLion 2022.3.3/bin/mingw/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/include/c++/bits/locale_conv.h:41,
                 from D:/Program Files/CLion 2022.3.3/bin/mingw/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/include/c++/locale:43,
                 from D:/Program Files/CLion 2022.3.3/bin/mingw/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/include/c++/bits/fs_path.h:37,
                 from D:/Program Files/CLion 2022.3.3/bin/mingw/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/include/c++/filesystem:45,
                 from D:/Projects/searchengineproject/vocabulary/game/src/rendering/Texture.h:6,
                 from D:/Projects/searchengineproject/VokabelTrainer/game/src/GlobalHelper.h:3,
                 from D:\Projects\searchengineproject\vocabulary\game\src\rendering\HierarchyPanel.h:3,
                 from D:\Projects\searchengineproject\vocabulary\game\src\rendering\HierarchyPanel.cpp:1:
D:/Program Files/CLion 2022.3.3/bin/mingw/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/include/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h:469:19: note: declared here
  469 |       unique_ptr& operator=(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
      |                   ^~~~~~~~
mingw32-make[3]: *** [game\CMakeFiles\game_lab_3.dir\build.make:316: game/CMakeFiles/game_lab_3.dir/src/rendering/HierarchyPanel.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:2095: game/CMakeFiles/game_lab_3.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:2102: game/CMakeFiles/game_lab_3.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:1047: game_lab_3] Error 2

I have read about similar problems on the internet but the solutions were all about avoiding the use of a copy constructor, which should be defined in my case.
What could I be missing?

As the error message says, Scene cannot be copied because std::unique_ptr<Entity> ent cannot be copied.

Suppose you have Scene a; Scene b; ...; a = b;. What should this assignment do to b.ent given that ent is a unique pointer? If you want to duplicate a pointee and create a new unique pointer that points to a copy, you'll need to implement a copy constructor and copy assignment yourself, in pseudo code something like a.ent = std::make_unique<Entity>(*b.ent)).

Can you maybe tell me what I can do about that?

@notfynnaf If you want Scene to be copyable it cannot contain a unique_ptr so either you have to remove the unique_ptr or remove the copying.

@john so my entities and components can't be unique_ptrs? like none of them?

@notfynnaf This has nothing to do with Entity BTW. Any unique_ptr in any class will (by default) prevent that class from being copied.

The problem with pointers is that they cannot be safely copied, because as soon as you copy the pointer you have two pointers to the same thing and it's hard to know when to delete the pointer. unique_ptr doesn't solve that problem, it just makes you aware when you have that problem by causing compliation errors.

First question to ask is "Does it make sense to copy a Scene? If not, make it impossible. If copying a Scene is desirable you will have to rework its internals so that they are all copyable OR make a copy constructor that clones the uncopiable.

@john if you don't mind the question, as my programming skills are still not very developed, do you see any problem why it would not work if I just use regular pointers instead of unique_ptr s?

If you want to copy pointers then you basically have two choices, use a shared_ptr (which can be copied) or use a unique_ptr in one place, and then when you want to copy it copy it as a raw pointer. That has the obvious problem that you might end up with a raw pointer to an object that has already been deleted.

@notfynnaf How would you know when to delete the raw pointer? If you have several copies of a pointer then you should only delete when the last one gets destroyed. In general that's a difficult problem to solve.

@notfynnaf Cloning as mentioned by user4581301 is another option. Don't copy the pointer instead allocate a new one that copies the object being pointed at.

it cannot contain a unique_ptr - this is not true. You just need to implement a proper Scene copy constructor, that will copy Entity into a new unique pointer. But it's unclear why you ever need a pointer.

A note about shared_ptrs, they typically need to be shared beginning to end to prevent  screw-ups. So you start with std::make_shared and, for example, rather than T* GetOrAdd(), you would likely want std::shared_ptr<T> GetOrAdd().

One reason for pointers is to keep the address returned by GetOrAdd from being invalidated by subsequent calls to GetOrAdd. That said, keeping the pointer alive long enough for the next call to GetOrAdd to become a problem often means you're digging yourself into a deeper hole and should seriously consider paying the extra overhead of shared_ptr.

@3CxEZiVlQ do you have an examplee on how to get this copying to work in a copy constructor? thanks for all the explanations anyway!

@user4581301 so a shared_ptr might work better?

Simplifies your code a lot and protects you from the Scene going out of scope before other pieces of code still using its components, but it could send the wrong message. unique_ptr tells the reader that Scene is the one and only owner of the component. The component passes on when Scene does. The two are inextricably linked. shared_ptr tells the reader that your system is more dynamic and that you don't really know for sure when a component will expire. I don't think that's the case here, and unique_ptr is the correct, but somewhat more difficult, choice.

But before you do anything, first make sure that copying Scene makes sense, because if it doesn't make sense, making it copiable is wasted time and will probably allow bugs that the compiler could pick off to creep in.

do you have an examplee on how to get this copying to work in a copy constructor? Use the search button, don't raise immediate questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030081/copy-constructor-for-a-class-with-unique-ptr

Note that because you have a container of unique_ptr, it's not quite as easy.  You'll need a loop to clone all of the components and it's probably easiest if you build the loop into a helper function so you can still make use of the member initializer list. Eg: https://godbolt.org/z/4ooqcYzoM

But again: a lot of unnecessary work if it doesn't make sense to copy a Scene.

std::unique_ptr cannot be assigned to another (rvalue) std::unique_ptr. This is because when the original unique_ptr deletes its data, the remaining copy of it would be a dangling pointer (bad).
If you would like to delete the previously allocated data and swap it with the new one, use the reset method.
If you would like to move the ownership (essentially change which unique_ptr should be responsible to delete and contain the data), you can use std::move to assign a unique_ptr to another unique_ptr.
For example:
class Integer
{
  public:
    int data;
    Integer(int _data) : data(_data)
    {std::cout << “made integer ” << _data << “\n”;
    ~Integer(){std::cout << “destructed integer ”
        << data << “\n”;}
}
int main()
{
  std::unique_ptr<Integer> iptr = 
          std::make_unique<Integer>(5);
  std::cout << *iptr << “\n;
  std::unique_ptr<Integer> new_owner = 
          std::move(iptr);
  new_owner.reset(new Integer(10));
  std::cout << *new_owner << “\n”;
}

output
made integer 5
5
destructed integer 5
made integer 10
10


Not only std::unique_ptr is move-only, but also your Entity class is. You have stated that Entity cannot be copied 4 times via code:

Implicitly through members:

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>> components;

Because of std::unique_ptr, components and consequently the Entity are move-only.

Declaring move constructor.
Declaring move-assignment.
Explicit deleteing

Since both std:: unique_ptr and Entity are move-only, trying to make Scene copy-constructible or copy-assignment essentially leads to erroneous code. So, you should decide if you want Scene move-only or not.

In the former case,
Using Entity by value is faster, simpler and easier:

class scene{
    Entity ent={};
    /*Rest of definition s*/
};


In the later case,
Using std::shared_ptr, you can rely on reference counting fo memory management:

class scene{
    std::shared_ptr<Entity> ent = std::make_shared<Entity>();
    /*Rest of definition s*/
};

You must make sure however to not create circular dependecy.
Another issue with your snipet is Entity::GetOrAdd. Since the function never nullptr, it doesn't need to use pointer syntax. Using reference would show your intent of immediate access:
    template<typename T>
    T& GetOrAdd(){
        /*Blah blah*/
        return *result;
        /*Blah blah*/
        return *components.back();
    };

The get member of smart pointers is only meant to be used as parameter to legacy C API functions:
static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<my_record>);
std::unique_ptr<std::FILE, void(*)(std::FILE*)>
file_ptr{std::open("myfile.dat", "rb"), std::fclose};
std::vector<my_record> my_vec{my_count};
std::fread(data(my_vec), sizeof(my_record), size(my_vec),file_ptr.get());

You need to make up your mind about the ownership of pointers. If the owner is unique, then std::unique_ptr makes its owner move-only. If the ownership is shared, then the last living owner deletes the object pointed to by std::shared_ptr as part of its destruction. If any object is supposed to have an independent copy of data, then value semantics should be aquired; no pointers suit that case.
