# Copy constructor for a class that has unique ptr of a Base class

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

When a class has a unique_ptr of a Base class what is a good way to implement the copy constructor.

Let me try to explain it with an example:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual void doSth() = 0; // to make the class abstract.
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    virtual void doSth() override {}
};

struct Foo
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base> bar;

    Foo(const Foo& other) : bar(new Base(*other.bar))   // cant do it, its abstract.
    {
        bar = std::move(other.bar); // cant do it, reference object is modified.
    }
};
```

Here as the class is abstract i cannot use its copy constructor. and also cannot use move on a constant reference ( we shouldnt do it actually, do not modify the object).

What I end up with is like so:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual void doSth() = 0; // to make the class abstract.
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    virtual void doSth() override {}

    Derived(const Base* b)
    {

    }
};

struct Foo
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base> bar;

    Foo(const Foo& other) : bar(new Derived(other.bar.get()))
    {

    }
};
```

However, it does not feel quite right, does it?

Comment: @40two Actually, i have seen the question you referenced before. But, maybe I could not put it clearly. My concern is about unique_ptrs of abstract Base classes and how to handle them in copy constructors.

Comment: Thanks for the point, you are right I'm removing my comment.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255546/c-deep-copying-a-base-class-pointer) for how to deep copy an object using only the base class pointer.

Comment: If you want to copy the pointed-to object, the standard way is via a virtual `clone()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to copy polymorphically, you will need to provide that in the interface of the type you are holding. Add a `clone` virtual function to `Base` and use that to create a *copy* that you can store in the copied `Foo`.

Other alternatives include not copying (delete the copy constructor) or use reference semantics (copies refer to the same object: change `unique_ptr` for `shared_ptr`) but neither of those alternatives really provide *copies*.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code for David's answer. Note that the virtual `clone()` is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12255574/391161).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstddef>
#include <memory>


struct Base
{
   virtual void doSth() = 0; // to make the class abstract.
   virtual Base* clone() const = 0;
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    virtual void doSth() override {}
    virtual Derived* clone() const {
        return new Derived(*this);
    }
};

struct Foo
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base> bar;

    Foo(const Foo& other) : bar(other.bar->clone())   // cant do it, its abstract.
    {

    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the modified code.